# Why am I getting a page token error while using the live chat API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to get the live chat of the live stream:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHtuITYCqcM`.

So for that, I made the URL:

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=xHtuITYCqcM&key=...`,

and it returns the following:

```json
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "page token is not valid.",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "page token is not valid.",
            "domain": "youtube.liveChat",
            "reason": "pageTokenInvalid"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

If anyone knows why is this happening, please help me.

I'm new to this platform, so if I missed anything, please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the official specification of the [`LiveChatMessages.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) API endpoint, its request parameter [`liveChatId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list#liveChatId) is defined as follows:

> [**`liveChatId`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list#liveChatId) (string)
>
> The `liveChatId` parameter specifies the ID of the chat whose messages will be returned. The live chat ID associated with a broadcast is returned in the `liveBroadcast` resource's `snippet.liveChatId` property.

Consequently, passing to this endpoint the respective stream's video ID -- `xHtuITYCqcM` -- is incorrect.

You'll have to invoke, as specified above, the [`LiveBroadcasts.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) API endpoint, passing to it the request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#id) set to your stream's video ID -- that is `xHtuITYCqcM` -- by means of an URL like this one:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?id=xHtuITYCqcM&part=snippet&fields=items.snippet.liveChatId&access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN`

where `$ACCESS_TOKEN` is the access token obtained upon running to successful completion an OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flow.

Note that the OAuth flow is actually required (an API key does not suffice), because:

> [**Authorization**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#auth)
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication)).
>
> **Scope**
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`

Also note that above I used the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to get from the API only the info that's of actual use (a good practice).

Comment: oh ok, so i followed a video, where they showed how to get the key, but, i did not start the live stream, so how do i get the id?

Comment: You should get all live streams including upcoming and completed streams if you did not specify the `broadcastStatus` option for [LiveBroadcasts.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list). Maybe you have set it to 'active'?