# YouTube Data API v3 invalid page token

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to request the messages of a live-stream chat via Youtube Data API V3. The problem is that it didn't find the page token. I get following error:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "page token is not valid.",
    "errors": [{
      "message": "page token is not valid.",
      "domain": "youtube.liveChat",
      "reason": "pageTokenInvalid"
    }]
  }
}
```

This is my JS:

```js
gapi.load('client', start);

function start() {
  fetch('config.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(config => {
      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: config.apiKey,
        discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest"]
      }).then(function() {
        var liveChatId = config.liveChatId;

        function getChatMessages(pageToken) {
          gapi.client.youtube.liveChatMessages.list({
            liveChatId: liveChatId,
            part: 'snippet',
            pageToken: pageToken
          }).then(function(response) {
            var chatDiv = document.getElementById('chat');

            response.result.items.forEach(function(item) {
              var message = item.snippet.displayMessage;
              var messageElement = document.createElement('div');
              messageElement.className = 'chat-message';
              messageElement.textContent = message;
              chatDiv.appendChild(messageElement);

              setTimeout(function() {
                messageElement.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
                setTimeout(function() {
                  chatDiv.removeChild(messageElement);
                }, 500);
              }, 10000);
            });

            if (response.result.nextPageToken) {
              getChatMessages(response.result.nextPageToken);
            }
          });
        }

        getChatMessages();
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Fehler beim Laden der Konfigurationsdatei: ' + error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68660321/519413

Comment: @roryMcCrossan already Saw this but didnt Help. They changed the API every Month